# Google Chrome: payments API returns purchase failed while transaction is successful

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-api, in-app-purchase

I am using the payments API for an in-app purchase inside a Chrome extension.

I am able to initiate a purchase, which works and activates the transaction, But the callback goes to onPurchaseFailed instead of onPurchase.

manifest:

```
"offline_enabled": true,
"name": "__MSG_name__",
"description": "__MSG_description__",
"manifest_version": 2,
"version": "1.1.2",
"default_locale": "en",
"icons": {
    "128": "style/128_on.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [ "js/jquery.min.js","js/bg.js" ]
},
"browser_action": {
   "default_title": "__MSG_name__",
   "default_icon": "style/128_off.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"key": "...",
"oauth2": {
"client_id": "...",
"scopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly" ]
},
"permissions": [ "*://*/*", "activeTab", "tabCapture", "tabs" ]
```

API buy method:

```
google.payments.inapp.buy({
    parameters: {'env': "prod"},
    'sku': sku,
    'success': onPurchase,
    'failure': onPurchaseFailed
});
```

I'm getting:

```
onPurchaseFailed Object{
  checkoutOrderId:"10370910..."
  response:Object{
    errorType:"PURCHASE_CANCELED"}
}
```

The license gets activated however:

```
google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
  'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
  'success': onLicenseUpdate,
  'failure': onLicenseUpdateFail
});
```

returns  :

```
createdTime: //some number
itemId: //some string
kind:"chromewebstore#payment"
sku: //some string
state:"ACTIVE"
```

I have a suspicion that this happens because the purchasing window sends a cancellation message when it closes, which triggers the onPurchaseFailed callback. How to handle this?

Comment: any conclusions regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found is to check the payment at failure callback